# extracting coefficient p values rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

I am using `rpy2` to embed some R in python, and calling `lm` from within python. My goal is to to extract the parameter t-stat or p values. I am not sure how to do it. In general in R I use `summary(model)$coefficients[1,4]`. How do I call that in python environment?

Answer (score 2):

There is *some* (but not much) useful information in [the rpy2 docs](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html#linear-models) and [the Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html#transferring-r-data-sets-into-python).

It appears that the best way to retrieve the detailed results of an `R` command is as follows.

We start with the usual imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import r as R
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

stats = importr('stats')
base = importr('base')
```

Now run the linear model in R and retrieve the coefficients:

```
# Equivalent of lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data='iris')
lm = stats.lm("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width", data=R['iris'])
# Equivalent of summary(lm)
summary = base.summary(lm)
# Extract the coefficients
coeffs = summary.rx2('coefficients')
```

We can then create a Pandas dataframe from the `coeffs` object:

```
# Build a DataFrame from the coefficients tables
df = pd.DataFrame(pandas2ri.ri2py(coeffs),
             index=coeffs.names[0], columns=coeffs.names[1])
```

This now enables us to use the coefficients as we would normally in Python:

```
In [11]: df['Pr(>|t|)'] # p-values!
Out[11]:
(Intercept)    6.469702e-28
Sepal.Width    1.518983e-01
Name: Pr(>|t|), dtype: float64

In [12]: df.loc['Sepal.Width', 'Pr(>|t|)']
Out[12]: 0.15189826071144744
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this covered in the introduction to rpy2 ?

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/introduction.html#linear-models

Comment: Apparently not. (At least not that I could find.)